# Subversion Client-Side application

Tags: windows, svn

Which **standalone Windows GUI application** do you recommend for use for accessing a Subversion repository?

Edit: A lot of people are mentioning Tortoise, however I am looking for an application not a shell extension.  Also people are questioning my reasoning behind not wanting to use a shell extension.  In our environment we rather interact with the repository (when not using an IDE plugin) through a management application and not navigate the files through Windows Explorer.

Comment: Why do you need the application vs. the shell extension? That would make it easier to answer this question.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**Standalone Clients**

For total stand alone [Synchro SVN](http://www.syncrosvnclient.com/) is a powerful and cross platform solution.  It looks like the most native application on each of the platforms.

The [Subversion website](http://subversion.tigris.org/links.html#clients) includes a listing of other **standalone SVN Clients** (most are cross platform).  [Copied list below from http://subversion.tigris.org/links.html#clients]

**eSvn** - cross-platform QT-based GUI frontend to Subversion
http://sourceforge.net/projects/esvn

**FSVS** - fast subversion command-line client centered around software deployment
http://fsvs.tigris.org/

**KDESvn** - A Subversion client for KDE
http://www.alwins-world.de/wiki/programs/kdesvn

**QSvn** - A cross-platform GUI Subversion client
http://ar.oszine.de/projects/qsvn/

**RapidSVN** - A cross-platform GUI front-end for Subversion
http://rapidsvn.tigris.org/

**RSVN** - Python script which allows multiple repository-side operations in a single, atomic transaction.
https://opensvn.csie.org/traccgi/rsvn/trac.cgi/wiki

**SmartSVN** - A cross-platform GUI client for Subversion
(Not open source. Available in a free and a commercial version.) 
https://www.smartsvn.com/

**Subcommander** - A cross-platform Subversion GUI client including a visual text merge tool.
http://subcommander.tigris.org/

**SvnX** - A Mac OS X Panther GUI client.
http://www.lachoseinteractive.net/en/community/subversion/svnx/

**Syncro SVN Client** - Cross-platform graphical Subversion client.
(Not open source. Free trial versions available for Mac OS X, Windows and Linux.)
http://www.syncrosvnclient.com

**WorkBench** - Cross platform software development GUI built on Subversion written in Python
http://pysvn.tigris.org/

**Versions** - A GUI Subversion client for Mac OS X.
(Not open source; requires commercial license.) 
http://www.versionsapp.com/

**ZigVersion** - a Subversion Interface for Mac OS X. Aims to design an interface around the typical workflows of programmers.
(Note that this is not open source.) 
http://zigversion.com/

**Integrated Clients**

[TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) is the best general use system [An integrated system is not standalone - Thanks Martin Kenny].  It integrates itself into Windows Explorer (You can use it in explorer or any shell dialog) so it works extremely well and gives you the full power of SVN.

[Ankhsvn](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/) is a good solution that integrates into Visual Studios (Except Express Editions).

[SVN Notifier](http://svnnotifier.tigris.org/) monitors your repositories and will notify you when anything changes.  It integrates with TortoiseSVN to show you diffs and commit logs.  Very handy when working in a team environment.

Comment: RapidSVN worked great, small download, straight forward no windows integration, just what I needed. Plus it's free ; )

Answer (score 25):

[TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/)

From their website:

> A Subversion client, implemented as a windows shell extension.
>
> TortoiseSVN is a really easy to use Revision control / version control
>   / source control software for Windows. Since it's not an integration
>   for a specific IDE you can use it with whatever development tools you
>   like. TortoiseSVN is free to use. You don't need to get a loan or pay
>   a full years salary to use it.

Comment: I second that answer.  Its basically a shell extension type thing. I'm not sure if that meets your requirement for "standalone windows GUI application.

Comment: Explorer integration is a big plus if you are using windows.

Comment: Even though the asker specified they didn't want to use the shell extensions, they should probably reconsider unless they have a really good reason.  Tortoise is definitely the best way I've experienced to interact with Subversion from Windows.

Comment: I suspect his reason is similar to mine: I use Git primarily and rarely do use SVN. So I want a simple client to get in and interact with SVN only when I need it, not cluttering up explorer all the other time.

Answer (score 5):

You can try to use SmartSVN - https://www.smartsvn.com/

Comment: Aye - there's my vote. Kudos to any product whose documentation is written in TeX :)

Answer (score 2):

Can you explain why TortoiseSVN doesn't work for you? That would help us figure out what you really need in an application.

Combine TortoiseSVN with Windows Explorer and you've got a great tool, and then pickup VisualSVN if you want something to integrate with Visual Studio.

Comment: TortoiseSVN is not really a "Standalone Windows Client" because it integrates itself with Windows Explorer.  A standalone client would be one that is totally self contained and does not integrate with any other program They are useful for machines that you can't install or integrate on.

Answer (score 1):

As a shell extension, I guess it's not technically a stand-alone application, but +1 for TortoiseSVN, nevertheless.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) to get started with (basically, it adds SVN related contextual menus to explorer), but it can be shockingly memory hungry.

I generally use it when I need to, but also make use of the very clean and usable command line tools subversion comes with and Subclipse as part of Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

For total stand alone [Synchro SVN](http://www.syncrosvnclient.com/) (60$) is one of the nicest looking and full featured ones.  It is cross-platform (Win, Linux, OSX).

Answer (score 1):

The one and only [tortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/downloads)!

It is integrated in Windows Explorer, you invoke it with a right click. All commands are under the TortoiseSVN menu, except for frequently used commands such as **update**, **commit** or **diff** (it's configurable).

For some reason, the SVN proterties are located in a tab in the Properties menu, not in the TortoiseSVN menu. It makes sense, sort of, but it took some time getting used to it.

TortoiseSVN is excellent, but I only realised it was awesome when I moved to a Mac (where Tortoise is not available) and tried to find a decent tool. Nothing comes close.

Answer (score 1):

[SmartSVN](https://www.smartsvn.com/) is nice if you want a client that doesn't integrate with Explorer and is instead a standalone app.  (Although I think later version offer an Explorer integration as well.)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't like shell extensions TortoiseSVN can be used as an application through its handy automation interface - one executable several command arguements.

See [TortoiseSVN Manual](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-automation.html)

Each command raises a modal dialog for a specific task.

Answer (score 1):

I use [PHPStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) from JetBrains

It can be used in MAC or WIN PC environment. It has internal subversion/git/mercurial tool.

though you do have to pay for it ($50) they have 30 day fully functional trial.

Answer (score 0):

Memory and disk IO can be a problem with TSVNCache, which manages Tortoise's icon overlays.  You can fix it by putting your checkouts in one or two directories and making the cache process only look at those directories, rather than your entire drive.

[See this link for instructions.](http://www.paraesthesia.com/archive/2007/09/26/optimize-tortoise-svn-cache-tsvncache.exe-disk-io.aspx)